# Replace x axis of highstock dynamic updated chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am working on highstock charts for the first time.
The link http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update gives me the solution I need.
But I would like to replace the x - axis values (currently date time) with some other values like length measurements. I would also like to change the date time shown in mouse hover in the above chart with the length measurement values. 

Could anyone help me find a way out as I don't see any other dynamic chart as far, specific to my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `formatter`'s to replace what is rendered, for example using `xAxis.labels.formatter` changed are xAxis labels. The same applies for `tooltip.formatter`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4uLe2gx6/1/

Comment: Thankyou Pawel.. That did work :)